# Refusing job offer after intership due to career growth

Tags: job-offer, internship, careers

**The main question:**

Is it advisable to refuse a job offer in a place you've worked as intern, if you fear it could be uninteresting, poor in terms of career growth, and generally not the best thing you could try?

**Background:**

I'm a (almost graduated) master degree student in Computer Science, currently ending my unpaid internship with company A. So far, while I do enjoy some aspects of the culture of A, I'm not satisfied with the internship; most days I've nothing much to do or I'm forced to wait for input from my overworked colleagues.
The project I'm on seemed interesting at first, but now - after months of little feedback and a rather disinterested attitude by, well, anyone - I'm disheartned and I don't care anymore. Of course, I could have been a better employee, but that's a tale for another day.

**The point is,** now that the internship is ending, everyone seems convinced that I'll receive a job offer soon. This is somewhat dreadful to me, since I'm not enjoying my stay, I'm struggling to care about the project and I don't imagine what my future in the company could be. 
Moreover, I'm not really conviced I'd like to work with the current technologies I'm using now in company A.

I'll add more meat to the fire and say that, given the actual hiring policy of company A, it's unlikely that I will work there for more than one or two years. As an almost new-grad, I'm well aware there are many things I don't know; I'm afraid of stagnating in a place that won't add anything relevant to my skill set (at least, nothing that I didn't learn through my internship already).

Comment: You can decline whichever job offer you want. It's an *offer*, after all. It sounds like you've already made up your mind about not wanting to work there, so I'm not sure what you're even asking here. If it's relevant, it's advisable to try to avoid ending up in a situation where you're unemployed.

Comment: @Dukeling, I'm asking to know everyone opinion on the matter. Even if my mind is almost made up, I fear I could be reasoning out of boredom or uneasyness. I've got plenty of colleagues who'd consider passing a job offer as being picky, and I'd avoid that; I'd like my choices ot be sensible given the context.

Comment: "Questions asking for **advice on a specific choice**, such as what job to take or what skills to learn, are difficult to answer objectively and are rarely useful for anyone else. Instead of asking which decision to make, try asking how to make the decision, or for more specific details about one element of the decision." ([More information](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2693#2695))

Comment: The question is: "Is it advisable to refuse a job offer in a place you've worked as intern, if you fear it could be uninteresting, poor in terms of career growth, and generally not the best thing you could try?" It's a general situation. If my explanations in the background section are misleading or prone to misunderstanding, I can edit them off.

Comment: "Do I have any obligation to accept a job offer from a company where I was an intern?" would be my suggestion for what *might* be an on-topic version of this question. Although that's making a possibly-incorrect assumption about why you think you can't just refuse the offer.

Comment: Start looking for a new job! Now. That being said, don't walk away from a potential job if you don't have anything else lined up (unless you can afford it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it advisable to refuse a job offer in a place you've worked as intern, if you fear it could be uninteresting, poor in terms of career growth, and generally not the best thing you could try?

*If* you get a job offer after your internship it is up to you to decide if you take it or not. In now way ever you *have to* take a job offer only because it was given to you.

It seems that you are not enjoying the company, so it could be wise to refuse such offer if they ever give it to you, and look for other jobs in places that are a better fit for your interests.

Before you refuse it, make sure that the offer they give you is of no interest to you. It could be that they offer you a somewhat different role, with new responsibilities and tasks. *If* you think you may like that then consider taking it, if it is the same role as your internship then I suggest you seek for other job.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it advisable to refuse a job offer in a place you've worked as
>   intern, if you fear it could be uninteresting, poor in terms of career
>   growth, and generally not the best thing you could try?

It would be foolish to accept a job offer for a position that you think is uninteresting, poor in terms of career growth, and generally not the best thing you could try.

Look at it this way: if this was a job you were interviewing for, would you accept an offer? If not, then don't accept an offer just because you were an intern.

Look elsewhere for a job that suits you. Start looking now.

(And if you are truly disheartened, don't care anymore and could have been a better employee, then don't be surprised if your employer notices and you aren't offered a job there anyway.)